# How to run "bundle exec jekyll new ."

Tags: ruby, jekyll, rvm, bundler, gemfile

I'm trying to follow "[Creating a GitHub Pages site with Jekyll](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll)" but when I run any of these commands:

```
$ bundle exec jekyll VERSION new .
$ bundle exec jekyll _4.0.0_ new .
$ bundle exec jekyll 4.0.0 new .
```

I get this error:

```
"Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory"
```

I have looked at several SO posts related to this error message, but none seem to have a fix for my problem. Perhaps I have missed something?

Some relevant details:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux]
$ jekyll -v
jekyll 4.0.0
$ type rvm | head -n 1
rvm is a function
$  lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.0.1ubuntu1-noarch:printing-11.0.1ubuntu1-noarch:security-11.0.1ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

Answer (score 32):

The GitHub walk-through left these commands out, but Bundler's [`bundle init`](https://bundler.io/v2.0/man/bundle-init.1.html) explains it:

This command is necessary to create the Gemfile:

```sh
$ bundle init
```

and this one to populate it with Jekyll:

```sh
$ bundle add jekyll
```

so that when I re-ran my setup command, it worked:

```sh
$ bundle exec jekyll 4.0.0 new . --force
```

The specific version of `jekyll` that GitHub uses can be found [here](https://pages.github.com/versions/).

Comment: brilliant, many thanks! It may be helpful to point out that `bundle` and `jekyll` should be on `$PATH`. I don't have write access to `/usr/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin` so I did `export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem`  and I prepended it to my path as `PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH`, which seems to work.

Comment: ty @plijnzaad.  Useful.