# Error upon `bundle exec jekyll 3.8.7 new .` for Github Pages

Tags: ruby, jekyll, bundler, github-pages

### Goal

Initiate a Github Page using Jekyll. I'm following the [Github Pages docs](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll).

### Problem

Upon executing:

`bundle exec jekyll 3.8.7 new .`

The following error is returned:

`fatal: 'jekyll 3.8.7' could not be found. You may need to install the jekyll-3.8.7 gem or a related gem to be able to use this subcommand.`.

Also note that (a) Jekyll 3.8.7 is the [current dependency version for Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/versions/) and (b) the same error is returned if I attempt it for Jekyll 4.1.0.

### Context

I tried the recommendation in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59913903/how-to-run-bundle-exec-jekyll-new) -- `$ bundle init`, `$ bundle add jekyll` -- but that didn't solve my problem.

System details:

```sh
$ which ruby
/Users/vishrutarya/.rbenv/shims/ruby

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin19]

$ jekyll -v
jekyll 4.1.0

$ which jekyll
/Users/vishrutarya/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin/jekyll
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, adding underscores did the trick.
I installed version 3.8.7 manually. With `gem list`, you can check if it is
actually installed.
Then i used `bundle exec jekyll _3.8.7_ new . --force` and it worked.

Comment: For me it was also the underscores which made it work, but I couldn't find what the underscores actually mean/do for this command.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same issue on MacOS. This is what I ended up doing:

1. Create a new dir, let's call it `blog`
2. Run `bundle init`
3. In the Gemfile, add the line `gem "jekyll", "= 3.8.7"`
4. Run `bundle i`
5. You can verify the jekyll version by issuing `bundle exec jekyll -v`
6. Create a `docs/` directory in the same folder
7. Run `bundle exec jekyll new .`
8. Run `bundle i` again in `docs/` directory
9. To serve, run `bundle exec jekyll serve` in the `docs/` directory

I hope this helps!

Comment: Step 5 threw an error: `zsh: command not found: jekyll`. 

Why would this have happened given I installed via `gem install --user-install bundler jekyll`? 

The output for that command in the next comment.

Comment: ```
Fetching bundler-2.1.4.gem
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/vishrutarya/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin in your PATH,
   gem executables will not run.
Successfully installed bundler-2.1.4
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.1.4
Done installing documentation for bundler after 2 seconds
Fetching jekyll-4.1.0.gem
Successfully installed jekyll-4.1.0
Parsing documentation for jekyll-4.1.0
Done installing documentation for jekyll after 0 seconds
2 gems installed
```

Is the problem "You don't have /Users/vishrutarya/.gem/ruby/2.7.0/bin in your PATH"?

Comment: For step 5 : if your system and project use different Jekyll gem then to get the project's Jekyll version, execute command `bundle exec jekyll -v` --> this will return `jekyll 3.8.7` along with some warnings

Comment: @dkb that makes more sense, I've updated my answer. Thanks!