# Install Jekyll but says: couldn't locate gemfile or bundle/directory

Tags: jekyll, ubuntu-16.04, gemfile

I just installed Jekyll, but when I type `bundle exec jekyll serve`, it couldn't locate *Gemfile* or *.bundle/* directory.

What should I do？

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run "bundle exec jekyll new ."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59913903/how-to-run-bundle-exec-jekyll-new)

Answer (score 1):

### First Install prerequisites

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full build-essential zlib1g-dev
```

### after that install the gem

```
gem install jekyll bundler
```

That’s it! You’re ready to start using Jekyll.

Source: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/ubuntu/